# What are used to construct the isometric circle?

Tags: geometry

I'm having confusion on what is being used to construct the isometric circle. My professor gave me 4 choices: Line, circle, ellipse, and semi-circle. I'm all new to isometric figures. Thanks for help

Comment: What is "the isometric circle"?

Comment: nope, the question is: ____ are used to construct the isometric circle. Is it line, circle, ellipse or semi-circle? Well my initial guess was circle. But I'm in doubt

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://www.technologystudent.com/designpro/isomet2.htm)?

Comment: If you don't tell us what you mean when you write, "the isometric circle", T. Mothy, how do you expect us to tell you how to construct one?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Isometric projection of circle]Ellipse.Because in isometric projection the visualization of circle converts to the shape of an ellipse.